# Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, error

suddenly I am getting this

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object"

in Magento ver. 1.9.2.4. I am just a beginner of Magento.

My site is working fine but suddenly arriving below fatal error. nothing change into code.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

any one have idea about this?

Comment: You need to add more lines of your error trace and where you are getting this error etc.